# Node js summary keeping paragraphs

Tags: node.js

Right now I am using the "text-summary" dependency on npm to summarize text. My problem is that the summarized text is not split into paragraphs and instead put into one huge chunk. For example, a piece of text 4 paragraphs long, once summarized, will be compressed into one paragraph:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Summarized would be:

AABBCCDD.

I would like it to be like :

AA

BB

CC

DD

Is there a simple way to compare an complete piece of text separated with paragraphs and a summarized piece of text in one paragraph and split up the summarized text into paragraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using RegExp global matches to match each paragraph out and summarize it.
add it to an array and at the end, dump all contents of the array into a string using

```
array.join("\n");
```

an example would be:

```
const text = "ABCD\nEFGH\nIJKL"; //your text
const match = text.match(/[^\n]+/g); //getting all instances that arent newlines
const results = [];
for (const i in match) {
    results.push(summarize(match[i])); //add summarized item to array
}
console.log(results.join("\n")); //print summarized paragraphs
```

Comment: you can also just re-use the match array that was created but this example was to seem more basic

Comment: Just for clarification, does "const i in match" mean to loop through match, word by word? Character by character? Thank you

Comment: global matches return an array containing all of the match data. in this case i matched all the groups of non newline characters. X in Y makes X the key of the next item in iteration for Y. also i made everything that could be constant const because it stores better than let. let should be used instead but only if the variables value will change, not if the actual thing it holds changes. (ie increasing it vs renaming the object it references)

Comment: if you want something like Luas "for key,value in next,tbl do end" you can do "for (key in tbl) {let value = tbl[key]}"

Comment: you can also use ("\t"+results.join("\n\n\t")) as this will nicely indent your paragraphs

Comment: Thank you so much! My problem is fixed :)